# If the absolute value of a series converges, can we say that the alternating series also converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinity

So I have the series -

$$\sum_{n=0}^∞ (-1)^{n+1} \frac{(2x)^n}{n!}$$

I know that by the ratio test, the absolute value of the above series converges for all $x$ (as $\rho < 1$). Since I know that the absolute value of the series converges, can I say that the alternating series also converges or does it not work like that?

If not, I'm not sure what test to use to prove that this alternating series converges for all $x$. Kindly help me understand how I can do that.

Comment: A strong test for convergence of any series is the convergence of the absolute value series.  Your series therefore converges.

Comment: If you mean the series of the absolute values, the answer is YES. And this is the concept of [ABSOLUTE CONVERGENCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence)..

Comment: So is it necessary for me to show that the terms in the series of absolute values is decreasing and that the series approaches 0 as 'n' approaches infinity?

Or is the fact that the series of absolute values is convergent enough for me to deduce that the alternating series is convergent too?

Comment: The question that is bugging me is, is it at all possible that the series of absolute values converges but the alternating series diverges?

Comment: No, Absoilute convergence impllies convergence.